# asp.net mvc 5 get name of variable passed into view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to get the variable name of the model i'm passing into a partial view, but am unable to figure this out. In the _MetricsTotal Partial View, how do I get "nameOfVariable"?

**Metrics Model**

```
public class MetricsModel
{
    public IEnumerable<MetricsDetail> metricsDetail { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<AttyList> attyList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MatterDataModel> matterdata { get; set; }    
}
```

**Controller**

```
    MetricsModel metricsData = new MetricsModel();
    //Logic to populate some metricsData
    return View("View1", metricsData);
```

**View1**

```
@{
    @model MVC5.Models.MetricsModel

    List<MVC5.Models.MetricsDetail> fooTotal = new List<MVC5.Models.MetricsDetail>();
    List<MVC5.Models.MetricsDetail> barTotal = new List<MVC5.Models.MetricsDetail>();        
}
@foreach (var item in Model.metricsDetail){
    //Logic to add some items to fooTotal and barTotal

    if (Request.Form["queryType"] != "foo")
    {   
        @Html.Partial("_MetricsTotal", fooTotal)
    }
    else{
        @Html.Partial("_MetricsTotal", barTotal) 
    }
}
```

**_MetricsTotal Partial View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MVC5.Models.MetricsDetail>

<p @{if(nameOfVariable=="fooTotal"){ <text>id = "fooTotalVariable"</text>}} Model.Sum(itemData => itemData.totalHours))
```

Comment: Have the partial view declare its own model.

Comment: @Jasen can you elaborate with some code? thanks

Comment: @Jasen i actually have it declaring the model i need already...sorry left that out of the original post...i edited my code

Comment: You are passing a collection so you need an index or foreach loop. What is `nameOfVariable` supposed to be? A property of `MetricsDetail`?

Comment: @Jasen nameOfVariable is supposed to be either "fooTotal" or "barTotal" that i pass into the partial view.  I don't need/want to use a foreach b/c i'm using `Model.Sum(itemData => itemData.totalHours))` to total up values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that label you'll need to pass that in as well.

```
@model MyViewModel

<div>@Model.Name</div><div>@Model.Data.Sum(m => m.totalHours)</div>
```

Make a new class

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<MVC5.Models.MetricsDetail> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then you call it in the parent view

```
@Html.Partial("_MetricsTotal", new MyViewModel { Name = "fooTotal", Data = fooTotal })
```

Comment: I would recommend using the nameof operator instead of hardcoding the name, moves a potential run-time exception to a compile time check.

Answer (score 1):

C#6 nameof operator => https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986596.aspx

Example

```
@Html.Partial("_MetricsTotal",new MyViewModel { Name = nameof(fooTotal), Data = fooTotal }
```